# Flutter set floatingactionbutton text on interval basis

Tags: dart, flutter, floating-action-button

I have the following widget which will fit into a different parent widget into its body section. So in the parent widget I call this widget as below
`body: MapsDemo(),`. The issue now is that at this section I run an interval where every 30 seconds I want to call api to get all the latest markers. 
Currently I print the count down as this codes `print("${30 - timer.tick * 1}");` My issue is very simple I have 3 three floating action button and I have given them their id. Thus on each count down for the last floatingaction button which is btn3.text I am trying to set its value as ${30 - timer.tick * 1} but it does not work on this basis. How can I update the count down in the button?

```
class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MapsDemoState();
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();      
      startTimer(30);
    }

    startTimer(int index) async {

      print("Index30");
      print(index);
      new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        if ((30 / 1) >= timer.tick) {
          print("${30 - timer.tick * 1}");
          btn3.text = ${30 - timer.tick * 1};
        } else {
          timer.cancel();
          var responseJson = NetworkUtils.getAllMarkers(
                   authToken
               );
          mapController.clearMarkers();
          //startTimer(index + 1);
        }
      });

  }

 //Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.contacts]);import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[

              GoogleMap(
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                   mapController = controller;

                 },
                initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(target: LatLng(3.326411697920109, 102.13127606037108))
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[  
                     FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () => print('button pressed'),
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.map, size: 30.0),
                      heroTag: "btn1",

                     ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () => print('second  pressed'),
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                        child: const Icon(Icons.add, size: 28.0),
                        heroTag: "btn2",
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () => print('second  pressed'),
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                        child: const Icon(Icons.directions_bike, size: 28.0),
                        heroTag: "btn3",

                      ),
                    ]
                  )
                  ),
                ),
            ]

         )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will display a countdown from 30 seconds inside of a `FloatingActionButton`.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'FAB Countdown Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const _defaultSeconds = 30;
  Timer _timer;
  var _countdownSeconds = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTime());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _getTime() {
    setState(() {
      if (_countdownSeconds == 0) {
        _countdownSeconds = _defaultSeconds;
      } else {
        _countdownSeconds--;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FAB Countdown Demo'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Text('$_countdownSeconds'), onPressed: () {}),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to call this function var responseJson = NetworkUtils.getAllMarkers(
                   authToken
               ); after every 30 seconds ended and start the next interval. What should I do for it to be waiting for the results to be back before I start the next interval?

Comment: @newbie Network calls are `Future`s so you can either wait to restart the interval when the `then` callback is hit, or use the `await` expression to return before restarting the interval.

Comment: I am a bit new to this Future concept anyway this how I have defined the function getAllMarkers  static dynamic getAllMarkers(String token) async { I have put the async in it but I am not sure should I leave the static dynamic to be part of it? So in this case the function is async where to define the then ?

Comment: @newbie You should read [fetching data from flutter](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data), [Dart futures](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures). You don't need to make your call `static`, but I would define the type instead of leaving it `dynamic`. `then` is a callback that you can use if `getAllMarkers` is a proper `Future` that returns appropriate values. Code after `await` will proceed only after your `Future` completes with a value. `await` just makes your code look like synchronous code.

Comment: I used static cause I was just following some example and the dynamic is cause it will either send a single string like failed or json. Is actually a rest api call. So based on your suggestion what is wrong ins my function definition and how exactly should I return my rest api value ?

Comment: [Network calls in Dart](https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-login-app-using-rest-api-and-sqflite-b4815aed2149). Scroll down to the `utils/network_util.dart ` section and review the syntax used for REST API calls.

Comment: thank you let me run through the link and I will get back to you. You suggest that I change like this is it. So meaning I restart the timer in the then section . But one thing in the example the definition says Future<dynamic> post(String url, {Map headers, body, encoding}) { but when I call I send only _netUtil.post(LOGIN_URL, body: {
      "token": _API_KEY,
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    }) . It does not send the header ,encoding is that fine? How to send them just put a comma?

Comment: A proper request should include headers and encoding params or you can run into a number of auth or response encoding issues. You would have to work with the owners of the REST API.